# role of R3 in this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis

Hi I am trying to relate Vx to Vf and Vf to Vin. However, R3 does not take any place in the equations. This question is so simple, yet I am very confused with it and stuck and spending last 2 hours getting through this. Can you help me what is going on? I am trying to forget everything I have ever learned. Center tapped resistors got me confused a lot.

Voltage divider equation at Vx and node equation at Vin.

[image: the circuit]

Comment: Look closely to your first equation. It seems that you are assuming that the current through R4 is the same as the current through R3 - are you sure this is correct?

Comment: @Vladimir Cravero no it is definitely wrong, there must be current leaking into ground but I could not write KCL properly. This is the first time I come across such a circuit

Comment: We don't hand out homework solutions here so you will need to show us a great deal of your own work here and ask a specific question. I suggest you start by redrawing the circuit.

Comment: What Elliot says is key. If you redraw the circuit, you will immediately see that R4 is in parallel with Vin - so R4 should not be present in the final relationship, not R3.

Comment: @Elliot Alderson the leaked current must come out somewhere and do you suggest going with that. This circuit kind of huge I just simplified it

Comment: What I think you're missing is something that troubled me for a long time. There's nothing special about "ground". But there's only one ground. So all three ground nodes are actually connected. As an earlier commenter said, redraw, with the three ground symbols connected. It'll make more sense.

Comment: What "leaked" current? In this circuit there is just **current**. Draw the circuit with all of the grounds at the bottom and the highest voltage at the top.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your circuit re-drawn.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fpi14H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>